# PHP page appears blank in subdirectories of localhost

Tags: php, wamp

I am new to webhosting and just installed a WAMP server on my system. index.php, testmysql.php and any other php files I put into C:wamp/www appear normally when I access them through localhost in my browser. However, if I create a subdirectory of www, for instance "MyProject", any php file I put into it appears blank when I try to access it through localhost/Myproject.

My PHP error log file contains the following messages:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found

Although these files are present.

Comment: Are you sure the files exist at the exact said path? I think they exist in `c:/wamp/bin/php/ext/` but not in `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/`.

Comment: `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/` is correct in my case. Look for those files and see where they are, might be bad installation.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - they are indeed in the extension mentioned in the error log. Some other posts suggest the files might be missing dependencies but I don't know how to check this.

Answer (score 0):

You can correct these errors

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found
>
> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found

By doing this using the wampmanager menus:

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9 ( click on the version number )
```

This will rebuild the SMLINKS in the apache/bin folder, and restart Apache.

To run code in a subfolder of \wamp\www\myproject you have to use this url in the browser `localhost/myproject/xxx.php` unless the file is called `index.php` and then you can just use `localhost/myproject` in the browser address bar.

Do not try and double click the file names using explorer, as if you do this the code will not be executed via Apache amd PHP and therefore the PHP code will not be compiled and run.